# How can I find who has the highest average grade using dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, input, printing

How can I find the highest average grade and the name of that student using dict?
There are only 4 students so I use a for loop for that.
The grades should print out in the same way the user inputted.
How can I also remove {} when I print the grades for the students?
Here is what I got:

```
grades = {}
x = int(4)
lst = []
for i in range(x):
    NAME = input('Student name: ')
    grade_nr_1 = float(input('Input grade number 1: '))
    grade_nr_2 = float(input('Input grade number 2: '))
    grade_nr_3 = float(input('Input grade number 3: '))
    the_sum = (grade_nr_1 + grade_nr_2 + grade_nr_3)
    the_average = the_sum/3
    lst.append(the_average)
    the_max_avr = max(lst)
    #print("{:.2f}".format(the_average))
    #print(grades)

    if NAME not in grades:
        grades[NAME] = set()

        grades[NAME].add(grade_nr_1)
        grades[NAME].add(grade_nr_2)
        grades[NAME].add(grade_nr_3)
    
    

for name,grade in sorted(grades.items()):
        #print(k,sorted(v))
    print(f"{name}: [{grade}]")

print(the_max_avr)
```

I'm expecting this:

```
Student name: alice 
Input grade number 1: 9.8 
Input grade number 2: 10.0 
Input grade number 3: 8.7 
Student name: john 
Input grade number 1: 6.7 
Input grade number 2: 9 
Input grade number 3: 9.5 
Student name: bob 
Input grade number 1: 8.8 
Input grade number 2: 6.7 
Input grade number 3: 5.6 
Student name: laura 
Input grade number 1: 9.4 
Input grade number 2: 9.7 
Input grade number 3: 10 
Student list: 
alice: [9.8, 10.0, 8.7] 
bob: [8.8, 6.7, 5.6] 
john: [6.7, 9.0, 9.5] 
laura: [9.4, 9.7, 10.0] 
Student with highest average grade: 
laura has an average grade of 9.70
```

Comment: Use a list instead of a set to store grades per student. Sets don't preserve order and ignore duplicates (if same grade appears twice, it will be stored only once).

Comment: Regarding the output there is a string method `join` to build a nice string out of a list (or other iterable).

Comment: yeah ur right thanks, any comment on how I could find the name with the highest average?

Comment: In `lst` store tuples `(the_average, NAME)`. `max` will then find the tuple with highest average together with the name. Only problem would be if multiple people have the same highest average.

Comment: Like this? `lst.append(the_averagen, NAME)`. I get an error with this. Could you make an answer to the question not a comment? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
grades = {}
max_avg = 0
x = int(4)
lst = []
for i in range(x):
    NAME = input('Student name: ')
    grade_nr_1 = float(input('Input grade number 1: '))
    grade_nr_2 = float(input('Input grade number 2: '))
    grade_nr_3 = float(input('Input grade number 3: '))

    if NAME not in grades:
        grades[NAME] = list()

        grades[NAME].append(grade_nr_1)
        grades[NAME].append(grade_nr_2)
        grades[NAME].append(grade_nr_3)
    
    

for name,grade in sorted(grades.items()):
        #print(k,sorted(v))
    avg = sum(grade) / len(grade)
    if avg >= max_avg:
        max_name = name
        max_avg = avg
    print(f"{name}: {grade}")
print("Student with highest average grade:")
print(f"{max_name} has an average grade of {max_avg} ")
```

Here, I changed the data structure of grades variable to be list instead of set. The reason is that if you use the set as your data structure it will not be able to contain the element with the same value and it also allow you to print out the grade as you want without any additional code.

Comment: The question is: How can I find the highest average grade and the name of that student?

Comment: I have modified the answer you can try to use it and see if it is what you expect. Hope this help

Comment: Thanks I forgot to mention that if two students have the same highest average grade, then the student that appears first in the alphabetical order should be printed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Several suggestions

##### Use lists, not sets, to store the grades within each student.

In a set, two identical scores get squashed into one data element, which is not what you want.

##### Convert the dictionary into a list for sorting

A list is much more amenable to sorting

##### Sort by the average grade

If you use `reverse` sorting, the highest will come first

### Solution code below

If you only want the *highest* scoring student, don't use a loop at the end: just do it for index 0.

```
grades_dict = {}
x = int(4)
lst = []
for i in range(x):
    NAME = input('Student name: ')
    grade_1 = float(input('Input grade number 1: '))
    grade_2 = float(input('Input grade number 2: '))
    grade_3 = float(input('Input grade number 3: '))
    the_sum = (grade_1 + grade_2 + grade_3)
 
    grades_dict[NAME]={
        "name":NAME,
        "average":the_sum/3,
        "individual":[grade_1,grade_2,grade_3]
    }


grade_items_list = sorted(grades_dict.items(),key = lambda name_dict_pair:name_dict_pair[1]["average"],reverse=True )


for grade_items in grade_items_list:
    print(f"{grade_items}")
```